# How to get fetch record from table where if in future a particular coulmn gets a particular value then not fetch it,expanded further in detail below

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I was having difficulty even describing my problem. So I have table lets call is Table A which is a child table , it is foreign linked to its parent table using a column called 'contentId'. 
Table A has a column called type. There are 4 users which are client , witness1 ,witness 2 and 1st party. Each user updates the document in content table. On each updation the Table A gets updated too and the type column changes on each updation.1st party makes the final updation and the document is 'complete'. I want to show the record in a table in my html site. The table under which I want to show these records is called "Records which are yet to be completed" on my html site. Once the 1st party makes the final changes I want to move the record from "Records which are yet to be completed" table to "Completed Document" on the frontend.

I am stuck on how to fetch the records to show documents pending to be completed. 
I tried various queries like used NOT IN, BETWEEN but non of it worked.
you will get a a better idea looking at the picture of the SQL data of the Table A I have put.
Table A contains contentId, which is same for the 1 single document.
In theory the fetching will work by checking table A column type. If it finds type to be client , witness1 or witness 2 then it will show only 1 instance of that record under the table "Documents pending to be completed",however if it finds type to be '1stParty' further down the record, which means it has been completed, then it will not fetch the record.

I am sorry, I know it is very difficult to even describe my query.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb3Fx.png)

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. Instead of just giving us an abstract description of what you're trying to do, show us all the relevant code, example data, example of the expected output and what output you're currently getting.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a column to the database, it's not clear to me which table it would best belong in, but call it 'status'. Then you can use integer values, enums, or (if you must, although it's probably less ideal) a varchar text to indicate the status. If you have a set of rules about who must review it, you might make several columns, `reviewed_by_witness`, `reviewed_by_first_party`, etc (or `reviewedByWitness`, if that's your style preference). Those could all be type `bit`, then you just change the flag to true when each party reviews it.